# comapare the two same indexes in array and then get the sum of third index

Tags: php, arrays

Please have a look on my array. So, I need to group it by product and size over price. Means, Where the size and product are same get the sum of prices and then show in other array with this format. Product | Size | Price.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => size
        [1] => product
        [2] => date
        [3] => price
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Large
        [1] => test2
        [2] => 5/9/2016
        [3] => 14
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => small
        [1] => test3
        [2] => 5/10/2016
        [3] => 17
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => Large
        [1] => test2
        [2] => 5/9/2016
        [3] => 17
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => small
        [1] => test
        [2] => 5/10/2016
        [3] => 1
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => Large
        [1] => test
        [2] => 5/10/2016
        [3] => 1
    )
```

I have tried this

```
$counter = 0;
```

foreach(array_slice($top100SitesCSV, 1) as $key => $value)
    {

```
if (isset($topSiteArray[$value[1]]['price']) && isset($topSiteArray[$value[1]]['size']) )
    {
    $topSiteArray[$value[1]]['price'] = $topSiteArray[$value[1]]['price'] + $value[3];
    }
  else
    {
    $topSiteArray[$value[1]]['price'] = $value[3];
    $topSiteArray[$value[1]]['size'] = $value[0];
    }

}
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: what happens to the date

Comment: Date is not necessary? You can assume all the dates.

Comment: can you show desired outptut here @Zubair Mushtaq

Answer (score 0):

Pseudocode:

1. foreach($initial_array as $tmpArr){}
2. Concatenate $keyStr = $tmpArr[0].$tmpArr[1];
3. Push the $tmpArr to a $newArray with that given $keyStr
4. for all other $tmpArray-s you concatenate 0,1 and use that as ID to check if you have a key like that in the $newArray,
5. If you have, you just increment the price, if you DON'T have you push the temparray with that 'ID' string.
6. After you finish with all you can just convert the keys of the $newArray to numbers

Answer (score 0):

i`m not really sure if u meant something like this, but below you have simple example, it should be good start point. There should be added some data validation and you should add dynamic mapping of your label vel data table.

```
 $data = [ 
    0 => [0 => 'size', 1 => 'product', 2 => 'date', 3 => 'price'],
    1 => [0 => 'large', 1 => 'test', 2 => '5/9/2016', 3 => '5'],
    2 => [0 => 'small', 1 => 'test1', 2 => '5/9/2016', 3 => '10'],
    3 => [0 => 'large', 1 => 'test', 2 => '5/9/2016', 3 => '13'],
    4 => [0 => 'small', 1 => 'test1', 2 => '5/9/2016', 3 => '22'],
    5 => [0 => 'medium', 1 => 'test3', 2 => '5/9/2016', 3 => '5'],    
    ];


$labels = $data[0]; // extract labels from data table 
unset($data[0]); // delete extracted data

$result = []; // prepare results container

foreach($data as $product){ // loop through all products
    if(!isset($result[$product[1]])){ // if prod isn't in table create new result row
        $result[$product[1]] = ['size' => $product[0], 'item' => 1, 'price' => $product[3]];
    } else { // if it`s just increment item count and calculate total price
        $result[$product[1]]['price'] += $product[3];
        $result[$product[1]]['item'] += 1;
    }
}

var_dump($result); // you can filter out of that table results for less than 2 items, or just don`t save it to the result in above loop
```

## result

```
 array(3) {
  ["test"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(5) "large"
    ["item"]=>
    int(2)
    ["price"]=>
    int(18)
  }
  ["test1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(5) "small"
    ["item"]=>
    int(2)
    ["price"]=>
    int(32)
  }
  ["test3"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["size"]=>
    string(6) "medium"
    ["item"]=>
    int(1)
    ["price"]=>
    string(1) "5"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood your poorly described request:

**CODE**

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$raw = array(
    [ 'size',  'product', 'date',      'price' ],
    [ 'Large', 'test2',   '5/9/2016',       14 ],
    [ 'small', 'test3',   '5/10/2016',      17 ],
    [ 'Large', 'test2',   '5/9/2016',       17 ],
    [ 'small', 'test',    '5/10/2016',       1 ],
    [ 'Large', 'test',    '5/10/2016',       1 ]
);

$keys = array_shift($raw);

$products = array();
foreach ($raw as $item) {
    $item = array_combine($keys, $item);

    $size    = array_shift($item);
    $product = array_shift($item);

    $products[$product][$size][] = $item;
}

var_dump($products);
```

[Play with me on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/DuLo4)

**OUTPUT**

```
array(3) {
  ["test2"]=> array(1) {
    ["Large"]=> array(2) {
      [0]=> array(2) {
        ["date"]=> string(8) "5/9/2016"
        ["price"]=> int(14)
      }
      [1]=> array(2) {
        ["date"]=> string(8) "5/9/2016"
        ["price"]=> int(17)
      }
    }
  }
  ["test3"]=> array(1) {
    ["small"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> array(2) {
        ["date"]=> string(9) "5/10/2016"
        ["price"]=> int(17)
      }
    }
  }
  ["test"]=> array(2) {
    ["small"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> array(2) {
        ["date"]=> string(9) "5/10/2016"
        ["price"]=> int(1)
      }
    }
    ["Large"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> array(2) {
        ["date"]=> string(9) "5/10/2016"
        ["price"]=> int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:** I kinda shifted the size instead of copying, so it's not in the final $products array. but you see the logic and can hopefully adjust the code yourself.